# view dependencies within lyx file

Tags: pdftex, lyx, external-files, logging

I have a lyx file that has a bunch of child documents (tables) embedded in it. How can I generate a list of these external files that are included in my main file when I compile (pdflatex) it? This way I can make sure they are all present and get rid of any extra files hanging around.

Thanks

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble, and then view the end of the resulting `.log` (Document > LaTeX Log) for a list of the files included.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you back up everything before removing any files. In addition to `\listfiles`, you could go to File > Export > LyX Archive. If I remember correctly, that does not pick up everything though.

Comment: thanks! (definitely backing everything up) will this (`\listfiles`) pick up absolutely everything that is included i the file? images, other .tex files, etc.?